# Reorganise pushed commits, remove from branch to apply in other one

Tags: git

I have **two feature branches**, I made the mistake of **committing** and **pushing** some commits to a wrong branch here is the situation:

```
Branch1: commit1 -> commit2 -> commit3 -> commit4
```

All commits pushed to Branch1.

I want to remove `commit2` and `commit4` from the local and remote branches and from history. I don't want to touch master or any other branch, just remove two non-consecutive **PUSHED commits** from a **SPECIFIC branch**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove commits from a branch.
But you can recreate a branch from selected commits.

One simple way is to rebase in interactive mode (thanks [@Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5358968/steve)!):

```
git rebase -i SHA_commit1
```

This will give you a list of commits, something like:

```
pick SHA_commit2 log msg of commit 2
pick SHA_commit3 log msg of commit 3
pick SHA_commit4 log msg of commit 4
```

Remove the commits you don't want.
The commits after the first removed will be replayed.

---

Another way is to recreate a branch without the commits you don't want,
for example:

```
# switch to branch1 (if not already on it)
git checkout branch1

# rename it -> it will become the backup
git branch -m branch1-bak

# recreate branch1 from the good point, at commit1
git checkout -b branch1 commit1_SHA

# replay commit3
git cherry-pick commit3_SHA
```

Now, `branch1` has commit1 and commit3, the other two commits are not in it.

Comment: the situation is more complicated than my example, because I have more than 4 commits, so is there another way to just remove two commits (non consecutive)

Comment: Remove, no. You can revert those commits, but that's not the same thing. Note that `cherry-pick` accepts a range of commits, for example `cherry-pick A..B`, so you won't have to run hundreds of cherry-pick commands, but  only a few ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
git checkout branch1
git rebase -i commit2~
```

then reorder to have commit1->commit3->commit2->commit4

```
git format-patch commit2~
```

maybe it could be wise to copy .patch files away

```
git reset --hard commit2~
git push -f origin branch1
git checkout feature2
git apply commit1.patch
git apply commit2.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `git rebase -i HEAD~5` (where 5 specifies how many commits to include in interactive rebase).

You will be presented with a screen looking like this

[image: example]

Change `pick` with `drop` on commits you want to remove. This will delete the commits on your local repository.

All what's left to do at this point is to run

```
git push -f
```

This will force push your `reconfigured` branch to your remote repository

Answer (score 0):

This is easily possible. You start out with:

```
git checkout branch1
```

The situation is:

```
commit1 -> commit2 -> commit3 -> commit4
                                    ^ 
                                    |
                              branch1, HEAD
```

You can just ignore `commit4` as it is dangling at the end and will be lost anyways. But we have to get rid of `commit2` like this:

```
git checkout commit3             # set HEAD to commit3
git revert commit2               # create a "undo-commit2" commit
```

Now you have:

```
                                 branch1
                                    |
                                    v
commit1 --> commit2 -> commit3 -> commit4
                           |
                           +----> commit5
                                    ^
                                    |
                                  HEAD
```

`commit5` still contains the changes of `commit3`, only whatever changes `commit2` introduced are gone now.

To clean up the history:

```
git reset --soft commit1   # set HEAD to commit1, put the diffs into the index
git commit                 # ... and create a new commit from them.
```

Now you have:

```
                                 branch1
                                    |
                                    v
commit1 --> commit2 -> commit3 -> commit4
   |                       |
   +------> commit6        +----> commit5
               ^
               |
              HEAD
```

`commit6` contains exactly the same file contents as `commit5` without any intermittent commits.

Now, let your branch point to `commit6`:

```
git branch -f branch1
```

There you go:

```
commit1 --> commit2 -> commit3 -> commit4
   |                       |
   +------> commit6        +----> commit5
               ^
               |
           HEAD, branch1
```

Finally push to the remote:

```
git push origin branch1 -f
```

Just ignore `commit2 ... commit5`, they will be cleaned up by the garbage collection at another time. Until then, they are your safety net, if at any point you get confused, you can just check them out again and start over.